# How can send List<> Model From View To Controller using Ajax Jquery in Mvc3 asp.net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How Can I Send `List<int>` Roles Model? For example from view To Controller.
Using Ajax Jquery in Mvc3 asp.net not razor.
I'm using this code

```
var url = '<%:Url.Action("Roles","RolesManager") %>';
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'post',
    dataType: "json",
    traditional: true,
    data: $('#EditUserForm').serialize(),
    success: function () {
        $('#EditUserForm').submit();
    },
    error: function () {
    }
});
```

but when I debug the controller `List<int> Roles = null`.

mode in page like

```
<%: Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.UserRoles, new MultiSelectList(Model.UserRoles, "UserRoleId", "UserRoleName"), new { @id = "UserRoles", @class = "ddlUserRolesCls" })%>
```

Comment: Are you using an editor template ? How your views looks ?

Comment: did u set ur parameter correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It's a Model Bind List, in this case, you have to send the information using the same name of your parameter in the `name` attribute of html inputs tag and asp.net model binder will convert it on a collection on the post. Your javascript looks fine. Try something like this:

In the view:

```
<input type="text" name="roles" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="roles" value="4" />
<input type="text" name="roles" value="2" />
<input type="text" name="roles" value="8" />
```

in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Post(List<int> roles) 
{
    // process
}
```

Also take a look at this article:
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Change your viewmodel like this. Note that we have a `SelectedUserRoles` property of type **int array**.

```
public class EditUserRole
{  
  public List<SelectListItem> UserRoles{ get; set; }
  public int[] SelectedUserRoles { set; get; }
  //Also other relevant properties here
}
```

And in my Get Action,  fill the `UserRoles` property

```
public ActionResult EditUser(int id)
{
  var vm=new EditUserRole();
  vm.UserRoles=GetUserRoles();
}
public List<SelectListItem> GetUserRoles()
{
  var roles= new List<SelectListItem>();
  // the below is hardcoded. Get it from DB And fill it here
  roles.Add(new SelectListItem { Value="1",Text="Admin" });
  roles.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Editor" });
  return roles;
}
```

and in your view which is strongly typed to `EditUserRole`,

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedUserRoles,
              new MultiSelectList(Model.UserRoles, "Value", "Text"),
                          new { @id = "UserRoles", @class = "ddlUserRolesCls" })
```

When you post your form, you will get the selected Roles ID in the `SelectedUserRoles` property of the posted model.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(EditUserRole model)
{
  // check model.SelectedUserRoles
  // to do : Save and redirect
}
```

Comment: i needed all item in list not selected

Comment: i select roles from list and add selected roles to another

Comment: why do you need all items ? You can get it in your POST action in the same way you got in GET action.

Comment: because i have two Html ListBoxFor the first for roles and another for selected roles i needed to get all item from the second Html.ListBoxFor appove code get me the last selected item

Comment: use jquery for each loop to get the items from the second item and the send it.

Comment: ok how can i add selected item to model and send it with $('#FormID').serialize() as parameter to json

Comment: you can add it in the query string (same name as your property name or build an object which is similar to your viewmodel and post that)